# Why is this a bad question? How could it be improved?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently wrote [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351225/how-do-killstreaks-affect-mediguns) and almost *immediately* received two downvotes on the question, without any explanation as to why.

I added a comment, asking for clarification, but yet nobody has responded. I'll assume that the downvotes were justified, but it is not immediately apparent to me how this question could be improved. I tried to format it to the best of my ability, I researched the topic beforehand but could not find any clear answers aside from "I think ... but I'm not sure", etc.

*Please note that I'm not trying to complain about my question being downvoted. I'm trying to learn how to write a better question.*

Comment: looks fine to me. better written than a lot of questions ive seen, and has a clear focus. Im not super familiar with the game, so maybe someone thought it was an obvious answer, or that you didnt research enough, but Id say just ignore it and move on

Comment: I agree.. looks fine to me too.

Comment: @Dragonrage Thank you. I tried to research the topic as best as I could, but all that I could find aside from listings for Killstreak Mediguns was one topic on steam, where people were confusing "Strange" Mediguns with "Killstreak" Mediguns. While it might seem poorly researched, I genuinely do not consider Steam forum discussions credible in any way whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a now-deleted comment, the question posted doesn't show the least bit of effort. I was able to find the answer to this question in a Steam forum discussion posted in 2014, as well as many, many other results, by googling "how do killstreak mediguns work" (which, you'll notice, is automatically filled in as a suggestion).

Note that the downvote tooltip says exactly this, describing the meaning of a downvote as "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". It is not useful to ask yet again about a topic that is now years old.